# Alternate syntax for C functions taking another function as a parameter

Tags: c++, c, syntax, function-pointers

I recently learned that this is legal C :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo(int bar(int))
{
  return bar(42);
}

int bar(int x)
{
  return x * 42;
}

int main()
{
  printf("Baz = %d\n", foo(bar));
  return 0;
}
```

Compiles without warnings and runs as expected ( compiles and works fine even as a C program rather than C++ )

```
rep ~/Documents $ g++ -Wall test.cpp
rep ~/Documents $ ./a.out
Baz = 1764
rep ~/Documents $
```

Why isn't this syntax used more often or even mentioned anywhere?

Comment: Interesting... haven't seen that syntax before myself. Would've expected the signature to read `int foo(int (*bar)(int))`.

Comment: In parameter lists, function types are adjusted to pointer-to-function, just like array type are adjusted to pointer-to-element.

Comment: It's exactly the same as `int foo(int (*bar)(int))`. Not sure why it isn't used often though.

Comment: There's nothing particularly unusual or unknown about this. That's just a function pointer. Be careful not to mistake "I've never heard of this before" for "This syntax is used infrequently and is never mentioned anywhere"; they are two very different things. :)

Comment: It is unusual, because function pointer declarations are not written like regular function declarations

Comment: @rep_movsd: That's where decay comes in (what Kerrek and 0x499602D2 said). Your C book doesn't cover this? Or your C++ book? Wait, which language _are_ you using?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26559655/function-prototype-using-in-function-without-pointer for Standard reference

Answer (score -6):

Maybe because you can call a function inside of another function. Ths is way better clear than function as parameter. Although is used by frameworks to run callback functions. I prefer function from another function as normal developer.

Comment: This has nothing to do with calling functions inside other functions. His point is about using syntax other than pointer to function syntax.